# Where is the list of FIDE approved clocks?

Tags: fide, chess-clocks

I see many sellers selling dozens of clocks that claim to be FIDE certified/approved.

Reading FIDE info I see what is required, and it mentions approved clocks,  but I cannot find an actual list of what clocks FIDE has actually approved and made available for guidance so as to buy approved clocks without taking the word of some seller.

Answer (score 4):

The electronic chess clocks endorsed by the FIDE:

| # | Model | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.5.1. | DGT XL | 2007 |
| 5.5.2. | DGT 2010 | 2010 |
| 5.5.3. | Silver Timer | 2007 |
| 5.5.4. | Sistemco | 2009 |
| 5.5.5. | DGT 3000 | 2014 |
| 5.5.6. | CE Clock | 2017 |
| 5.5.7. | KK9908 Clock | 2017 |

Source: [FIDE Handbook - Standards of Chess Equipment and Tournament Venue; Section 5.5](https://handbook.fide.com/files/handbook/C02Standards.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Could you please [edit] your answer to mention the source? That gives it credibility and by the way it's [required](/help/referencing).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [document](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/Standards_of_Chess_Equipment_and_tournament_venue.pdf) that includes that. See section 5.5.